# How to login to Facebook on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swiftui, facebook-login

There are not many resources explaining Facebook Login with SwiftUI. I'm not sure whether my code requires a `ViewController` or not because Facebook's `LoginManager.login()` contains a `ViewController` parameter - however this doesn't really translate to SwiftUI.

Regardless, I am trying to login the user to Facebook when they click on the `Button` below:

**LoginView.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FBSDKLoginKit

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var auth: UserAuth
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image("launcher_logo").resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 100)
                    .padding(.top, 100)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    FBLogin()
                }) {
                    Text("Continue with Facebook")
                }.foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

when the `Button` is clicked, it initialises `FBLogin` below - which fires `login()` in its `init()`:

Model:

```
class FBLogin: LoginManager {

    let loginButton = FBLoginButton()
    let token = AccessToken.current
    let permissions = ["user_birthday", "user_gender", "public_profile"]

    override init(){
        super.init()
        logIn(permissions: permissions, from: nil)
        print("fb init()")
    }

    override func logIn(permissions: [String], from fromViewController: UIViewController?, handler: LoginManagerLoginResultBlock? = nil) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

However I'm not sure what to do from there. At the moment, only `fb init()` prints but I want to execute the login and listen to the login result.

Any idea?

Comment: you can use [UIViewControllerRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable) to deal with `UIViewController` stuff in SwiftUI

Comment: Thanks. Will `UIViewControllerRepresentable` allow me to create a custom button/style?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just create `LoginManager` instance inside `ObservableObject` and then customise login completion. You can easily use inside `SwiftUI View`. No need `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Here is my sample.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fbmanager = UserLoginManager()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.fbmanager.facebookLogin()
        }) {
            Text("Continue with Facebook")
        }
    }
}

class UserLoginManager: ObservableObject {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    func facebookLogin() {
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: nil) { loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in! \(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions) \(accessToken)")
                GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil){
                        let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
                        print(fbDetails)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare the class as ObservableObject if you have not any Published variable? I think you will need published variable, which stores if Facebook login is succeed?

Comment: This is much easier than creating a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Thankyou.

Comment: How simple it is without UIKit. I hope MSAL (microsoft) and Google should make their iOS authentication library as simple as Facebook.

Comment: I wish Google would change its sdk compatible with SwiftUI.

Comment: This won't compile. the `logIn` method's closure wants two arguments and you can't switch on `loginResult`.

Comment: Pretty new to swiftui and facebooksdk but it seems to work if you import FacebookLogin.

Comment: Further to @davidev's comment, AIUI `fbmanager` should be annotated with `StateObject`, not `ObservableObject`. The latter is for when the object is owned by a parent view and passed to this one as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on a callback wrapper for Combine to use Facebook Login and Graph API Request with SwiftUI: https://github.com/axmav/combine-extensions

```
LoginManager()
            .logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email])
            .flatMap { loginResult -> AnyPublisher<Account?, Error> in
                switch loginResult {
                case .failed(let error):
                    return Fail(outputType: Account?.self, failure: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                case .cancelled:
                    return Just(Account?.none)
                        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                    return GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name"])
                        .start(type: Account.self)
                }
            }
```